# How to use Android Material Theme Design Attributes with Titanium (colored status bar, ...)

Tags: android, titanium, cross-platform, material-design

I want to use the Android theme attributes for my titanium android application:

https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html
[image: Android Theme Attributes]

The application must be backward compatible to pre Lollipop (API 21) devices.

Comment: please check this github module :

https://github.com/nuno/Ti.DrawerLayout-Demo-Alloy-App

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Titanium SDK 4.0.0RC+ now directly supports Theme.AppCompat with tinted action bar and status bar using theme attributes which is backward compatible.

First update your titanium CLI and SDK To 4.0.0RC+

```
npm install titanium@4.0.0-beta7 (newest at the time of writing)
```

In your tiapp.xml make a reference to your theme definition:

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <manifest>
        <application android:theme="@style/materialTheme"/>
    </manifest>
</android>
```

and change the SDK version:

```
<sdk-version>4.0.0.RC</sdk-version>
```

Define your theme attributes: platform/android/res/values/custom_theme.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="materialTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#1565C0</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#0D47A1</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF80AB</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#757575</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#FF6E40</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">#FF4081</item>
    <item name="colorSwitchThumbNormal">#BDBDBD</item>
    <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">#BDBDBD</item>
    <item name="android:colorEdgeEffect">#FF4081</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped :) Can we sometime update these colors at runtime based on our requirement?